# how to solve meaningless characters on serial montior Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno

Hi i am new at Arduino Uno , i am trying to use imu sensor and read datas from it so i installed mpu9500 lib from arduino website and run one example from its lib. However as i open the serial monitor, it displays strange characters . I check the pin configuration many times and load different libs and examples  but i could not fix it.
Here is the codes i run.

```
#include "MPU9250.h"

MPU9250 mpu;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Wire.begin();
    delay(2000);

    if (!mpu.setup(0x68)) {  // change to your own address
        while (1) {
            Serial.println("MPU connection failed. Please check your connection with `connection_check` example.");
            delay(5000);
        }
    }
}

void loop() {
    if (mpu.update()) {
        static uint32_t prev_ms = millis();
        if (millis() > prev_ms + 25) {
            print_roll_pitch_yaw();
            prev_ms = millis();
        }
    }
}

void print_roll_pitch_yaw() {
    Serial.print("Yaw, Pitch, Roll: ");
    Serial.print(mpu.getYaw(), 2);
    Serial.print(", ");
    Serial.print(mpu.getPitch(), 2);
    Serial.print(", ");
    Serial.println(mpu.getRoll(), 2);
}
```

And this is what i get also i changed value of boud but nothing changed

```
01:10:23.688 -> ⸮7в⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮`f⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮f⸮⸮⸮~⸮⸮xxf⸮~⸮⸮fx⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮怘⸮
```

Answer (score 1):

Try running simple Serial print code at the same baud rate(115200) and check if your board is alright. Then run the following code once:

```c
#include "MPU9250.h"

MPU9250 mpu; // You can also use MPU9255 as is

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Wire.begin();
    delay(2000);

    mpu.setup(0x68);  // change to your own address
}

void loop() {
    if (mpu.update()) {
        Serial.print(mpu.getYaw()); Serial.print(", ");
        Serial.print(mpu.getPitch()); Serial.print(", ");
        Serial.println(mpu.getRoll());
    }
}
```